# Rails and MySQL diffrent time zones affect queries

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

An appointment record in MySQL

```
mysql> select * from appointment where id = 2 \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
                                 id: 2
                       care_unit_id: NULL
           provider_organization_id: 2
                         patient_id: 12
                       clinician_id: 10
                          public_id: NULL
                appointment_type_id: 3
                    scheduled_by_id: 3
              appointment_status_id: 1
appointment_status_change_reason_id: NULL
               scheduled_start_time: 2014-07-23 05:48:00
                      check_in_time: NULL
                     check_out_time: NULL
                 dictation_recorded: NULL
              dictation_transcribed: NULL
                 documentation_time: NULL
                           comments: 
                      documentation: NULL
                         created_at: 2014-07-23 02:48:54
                         updated_at: 2014-07-23 05:48:54
                       lock_version: 0
                      reminder_sent: 0
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The same record in Rails

```
1.9.1 :058 > Appointment.find(2)
  Appointment Load (45.3ms)  SELECT `appointment`.* FROM `appointment` WHERE `appointment`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1
 => #<Appointment id: 2, care_unit_id: nil, provider_organization_id: 2, patient_id: 12, clinician_id: 10, public_id: nil, appointment_type_id: 3, scheduled_by_id: 3, appointment_status_id: 1, appointment_status_change_reason_id: nil, scheduled_start_time: "2014-07-23 05:48:00", check_in_time: nil, check_out_time: nil, dictation_recorded: nil, dictation_transcribed: nil, documentation_time: nil, comments: "", documentation: nil, created_at: "2014-07-23 02:48:54", updated_at: "2014-07-23 05:48:54", lock_version: 0, reminder_sent: false> 
1.9.1 :059 > 
1.9.1 :060 >   Appointment.find(2).created_at
  Appointment Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `appointment`.* FROM `appointment` WHERE `appointment`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1
 => Tue, 22 Jul 2014 22:48:54 EDT -04:00 
1.9.1 :061 >
```

As you can see **created_at** differs by one day.

Now the problem is I can't use the **created_at** to form a query as expected

```
1.9.1 :073 >   Appointment.where("created_at >= ? ",Appointment.find(2).created_at.beginning_of_day)
  Appointment Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `appointment`.* FROM `appointment` WHERE `appointment`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1
  Appointment Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `appointment`.* FROM `appointment` WHERE (created_at = '2014-07-22 04:00:00' )
 => [] 
1.9.1 :074 >
```

As you can see the above query is supposed to return a record but the **created_at** value collapsed it.

I wanted to know how this scenario is tackled by rails users. Thanks

Comment: now update the queries and output to match the results of the new code.

Answer (score 0):

The time stored in the database is always in UTC.

The time read by the Rails app will vary depending on what your app timezone is set as - and yours is UTC -4, so your Rails app is reading them as four hours earlier as what your DB is storing them as. This is perfectly normal. The times are identical, just in different timezones.

Is this actually causing you any problems?

Comment: How to make the last rails command work ? Given my app is deployed in diffrent time zones.

Comment: In this rails generated query `Appointment Load (0.3ms)  SELECT appointment.* FROM appointment WHERE (created_at = '2014-07-22 04:00:00' )` how to set created_at = Exactly whatever the value was in db for Appointment.find(2).created_at

Comment: remove the `beginning_of_day` part, because it is making the times different.

Comment: No probs with time. Problem is with date.

Comment: no, the problem is with the time. '2014-07-22 04:00:00' does not equal '2014-07-23 02:48:54', in either the time or the date.

Comment: I'm sorry the condition is changed to ">="

Comment: If you see the actual date is 23 but in rails generated query its 22

Comment: and now what you expect to happen, will happen. It's different because it's working in UTC time - four hours different.

Comment: Yes I know its UTC but is there any way to convert them automatically based on MySQL system time zone